# Informing competing companies of other offers during hiring process

Tags: hiring-process, job-offer

I applied to two companies and made it through the interview process to the point where I am waiting for offers or otherwise.

I find company A far more attractive than company B. Company B extended me an offer and I am still waiting on company A.

Company A and company B are in direct competition, so I assume they are competing over applicants as well.

When I inform company A about my received offer, should I tell them that it is from a competitor of theirs? Will this make look more attractive or otherwise, and play into the hiring decision of company A? How much detail can/should I tastefully go into when informing company A to suit my best interest?

Should I let company A know they are my top choice?

Comment: I wanted to direct my question more towards what one should say when informing company A, rather than coordinating the process

Comment: The answers to that question seem appropriate to this question as well.  What is it that you are having difficulty with that is not addressed there?

Comment: What should I say specifically vs when I should let them know in the process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can tell them how much the competing offer was for, but saying specifically who made the offer is (a) not helpful to you and (b) discloses more about the other company's hiring process/needs than they would prefer. Get in the habit now of respecting company confidentiality even when not legally obligated to do so.

Comment: I don't want to tell them details so much as I want to say "I received an offer from another company in the industry", company A did ask me to keep them updated on my status with offers etc

Answer (score -2):

I would not inform Company A at all.  You know each company is interviewing multiple candidates.  They should be working off the presumption that you are interviewing at multiple companies.

What Company B offers you is completely irrelevant to your discussions with Company A.  Each negotiation is a separate process.  If I were hiring at Company A, and you put Company B's offer in front of me, I would congratulate you on your job at Company B and drop you from the candidate list.  I would not expect to be introduced into a "bidding war" for you.  After all, I didn't bring the other candidates in and ask you to underbid each other.

Comment: But company A asked me to keep them updated with my status in the application process with other companies

Comment: To me, that was an inappropriate request on their part.  There is something very odd going on between those two companies.  Tread carefully.

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear, I'm a student about to graduate so all companies ask this because they want to carry out the process in time with my schedule so they don't miss out on candidates. Neither company knows who the other is, but they ask about other offers so that they are in line with each other. My intention is not to disclose who I received an offer from, rather to inform them I'm moving along in the process and want to let them know my timeline. My question, now, is when letting them know my timetable is it appropriate or beneficial to also tell them the offer is from their industry?